tRPC types are not passing from server to client link to repo atatched as it is a lot of code to share
Here is the repo. The issue is the tRPC is not passing types from expressJs to my front end. Right now I am manually typing out the tRPC variables which makes tRPC kind of redundant. Here is the basic setup
express/index.ts
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import { createExpressMiddleware } from '@trpc/server/adapters/express';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';

import { appRouter } from './routers';
import { createContext } from './trpc';

const PORT = process.env.PORT ?? 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin(requestOrigin, callback) {
      if (
        !requestOrigin ||
        (process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS ?? '').split(',').includes(requestOrigin)
      ) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    }
  })
);

app.use(express.json());

morgan.token('date', () => {
  return new Date().toLocaleString();
});
app.use(morgan('[:date] :status :method :url - :response-time ms'));

app.use(
  '/trpc',
  createExpressMiddleware({
    router: appRouter,
    createContext
  })
);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;


express/trpc.ts
import type { User } from '@packages/prisma';
import { initTRPC } from '@trpc/server';
import type { CreateHTTPContextOptions } from '@trpc/server/adapters/standalone';
import { ZodError } from 'zod';

interface Meta {
  authRequired: boolean;
}
export const createContext = ({ req }: CreateHTTPContextOptions) => ({
  headers: req.headers,
  user: null
});

export const t = initTRPC
  .context<{
    user: User | null;
    headers: CreateHTTPContextOptions['req']['headers'];
  }>()
  .meta<Meta>()
  .create({
    errorFormatter(opts) {
      const { shape, error } = opts;
      return {
        ...shape,
        data: {
          ...shape.data,
          zodError:
            error.cause instanceof ZodError ? error.cause.flatten() : null
        }
      };
    }
  });

ui/utils/trpc.ts
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import type { TRPCLink } from '@trpc/client';
import { createTRPCClient, httpBatchLink } from '@trpc/client';
import { observable } from '@trpc/server/observable';

import type { AppRouter } from '../../../apps/express/index';
import eventEmitter from '../helpers/eventEmitter';
import Toast from '../helpers/toast/toast';

const url =
  process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL ||
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL ||
  'http://localhost:3000';

export const customLink: TRPCLink<AppRouter> = () => {
  return ({ next, op }) => {
    return observable((observer) => {
      const unsubscribe = next(op).subscribe({
        next(value) {
          observer.next(value);
        },
        async error(err) {
          //check if invalid token
          if (err.message.includes('Invalid token')) {
            return eventEmitter.emit('logout');
          }
          //refresh check
          if (err.message.includes('expired')) {
            const { accessToken } = await client.auth.refresh.query();
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', accessToken);
            const retry = next(op).subscribe({
              next(value) {
                observer.next(value);
                retry.unsubscribe();
              },
              error() {
                observer.error(err);
                retry.unsubscribe();
              },
              complete() {
                observer.complete();
                retry.unsubscribe();
              }
            });
          } else {
            // validation errors
            const validationErrors = err.data?.zodError?.fieldErrors;
            let message;
            if (validationErrors) {
              const errors = Object.values(validationErrors).flat();
              message = errors[0];
            } else message = err.message;
            Toast.error(message as string);
            observer.error(err);
          }
        },
        complete() {
          observer.complete();
        }
      });
      return unsubscribe;
    });
  };
};

export const client = createTRPCClient<AppRouter>({
  links: [
    customLink,
    httpBatchLink({
      url: `${url}/trpc`,
      async headers() {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        return token
          ? {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
          : {};
      }
    })
  ]
});


In useAuth.ts the user from const user shows as any.
  const initializeAuth = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) return setLoading(false);
    const user = await client.users.me.query();
    setUser(user);
  };

